# How to find the maximum likelihood estimator for the ratio $\frac{p}{1-p}$ of binomial parameters?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, maximum-likelihood

I'm working on this problem:

> A random sample of $n$ items is selected from the large number of items produced by a certain production line in one day. Find the MLE for the ratio $r$, the proportion of defective items divided by the proportion of non-defective items.

I believe I can make sense of this as follows. Let $N$ be the "large number of items produced." Assuming $N>>n$, we may model the number of defective items in the random sample as a binomial variable with parameters $n$ and $p$. The number of non-defective items in the sample will be a binomial variable with parameters $n$ and $q=1-p$.

We want the MLE for $r=\frac{p}{1-p}$. By the "invariance principle" for MLEs, this should be

$$\hat{r}_{MLE}=\frac{x/n}{1-x/n}=\frac{x}{n-x}$$

where $x$ is the number of defective items we observe in the sample. **Is this right?** I'm bothered by the fact that the problem does not specify the name of the number of defective items observed, so I must give an answer using my own notation. In other words, I must introduce the letter $x$.

I also get stuck trying to derive this result directly, without the invariance principle. The probability of observing $x$ defective items is

$$P(x;p)={n\choose x}p^x(1-p)^{n-x}={n\choose x}r^xp^n$$

But I don't see how to write this probability solely as a function of $r$, so I don't see how to show directly that this probability is maximized when $r=\frac{x}{n-x}$.

---

New Idea: if $r=\frac{p}{1-p}$, then $r-rp=p$, so $p(1+r)=r$, so $p=\frac{r}{1+r}$. Therefore the probability as a function of $r$ is

$$P(x;r)={n\choose x}r^x\left(\frac{r}{1+r}\right)^n$$

Differentiating with respect to $r$ gives

$${n\choose x}xr^{x-1}\left(\frac{r}{1+r}\right)^n+{n\choose x}r^xn\left(\frac{r}{1+r}\right)^{n-1}\frac{1}{(1+r)^2}=0$$

This implies

$$x\frac{r}{1+r}+rn\frac{1}{(1+r)^2}=0$$

So

$$xr(1+r)+rn=0 \implies xr^2+xr+rn=0 \implies xr+x+n=0$$

So

$$r=\frac{-n-x}{x}$$

This is close but obviously not the same as what I get when I use the invariance principle. **What have I done wrong?**

Comment: The maximum likelihood estimator (MLE) is functional invariant, meaning the MLE of $f(p)$ is also $f(\cdot)$ of the MLE of $p$, i.e., $\hat{f}(p)=f(\hat{p})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first solution is correct. For your second solution, note that
\begin{align*}
 P(X=x|r) 
 &= {n \choose x}p^{x}(1-p)^{n-x} \\
 &= {n \choose x}\left(\frac{r}{1+r}\right)^{x}\left(\frac{1}{1+r}\right)^{n-x} \\
 &= {n \choose x}r^{x}(1+r)^{-n}
\end{align*}
Which doesn't quite agree with your solution. In order to maximize $P(X=x|r)$, it is often easier to maximize $\log(P(X=x|r))$ instead. The solution is the same because $\log$ is strictly increasing. Note that
\begin{align*}
 l(r) := \log(P(X=x|r)) &= \log{n \choose x} + x \log r -n \log(1+r)
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
 \frac{\partial l(r)}{\partial r} 
 &= xr^{-1} -n(1+r)^{-1} \\
\frac{\partial^2 l(r)}{\partial r^2} 
 &= -xr^{-2}-n(1+r)^{-2}
\end{align*}
Since $\frac{\partial^2 l(r)}{\partial r^2} \leq 0$, $l(r)$ is concave and is maximized at $\frac{\partial l(r)}{\partial r} = 0$. Obtain
\begin{align*}
 \frac{\partial l(r)}{\partial r} &= 0 \\
 xr^{-1}-n(1+r)^{-1} &= 0 \\
 nr &= x(1+r) \\
 (n-x)r &= x \\ 
 r &= \frac{x}{n-x}
\end{align*}
Therefore, $\hat{r}_{MLE}=\frac{X}{n-X}$, which is precisely the estimator you obtained previously.